# What is the web service interface that Skype for Business uses for location queries?

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Skype for Business allows you to link to an external SNMP discovery tool, as documented here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412972.aspx

Where can I get the interface definition (WSDL, XSD, swagger or whatever) that defines what messages can be sent by the SfB server, and what responses are expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs this information, the specification document is available on Microsoft's site here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595797(v=office.12).aspx

In case you encounter broken links, the name of the specification is "[MS-E911WS]: Web Service for E911 Support Protocol"